# jquery animated div is ignoring its parent's overflow property

Tags: jquery

Aloha,

I have a div with the css `overflow: hidden` set. Inside it I have a div that I am using jquery to animate.

$('#innerDiv').animate({left: '-=100'}, 1000);

when i do this, I can see the innerdiv move outside the outter div even though I have overflow set to hidden.

Is this normal? How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `innerDiv` has `position:absolute`, then it is not affected by the `overflow:hidden` of the outer `<div>` element.

<s>Try giving it `position:relative`.</s>

**Example with absolute:** http://jsfiddle.net/FVdJL/

**Example with relative:** http://jsfiddle.net/FVdJL/1/

---

**EDIT:** Give the outer container `position:relative` and you should be able to keep `absolute` on the `innerDiv`.

**Example with relative:** http://jsfiddle.net/FVdJL/3/

Comment: that fixed the overflow issue, but messes up the positioning... top:0px; doesn't work

Comment: @Justin: I just updated my answer. Give the outer container position:relative and you should be able to keep absolute on the innerDiv.